# Tableau not showing all my data on dashboard but it has been read in and shows it read all the rows in

Tags: excel, data-analysis, dashboard, tableau-desktop

I created a dashboard in Tableau using an excel_file.xlsx and it has 2848 rows, but the dashboard is only showing data for 2806. However, at the data source it shows all 2848 rows were read in. I checked for filters but cannot find any on that could be causing this issue please help.
[image]

Comment: Is there a chance that some data is duplicated?  Tableau won't show the same row twice if it is identical.

Comment: thank you for your help! it was a hidden filter